# PlatformException(not-found, NOT_FOUND, null, null)

Tags: flutter

I hope you are well.

I am facing this issue while I am running Twilio app in android device and trying to create room. However, camera and microphone permission is granted.

Please share your feedback on this point.
Looking forward to hearing back to you.

Thanks in advance!

I tried to give camera and microphone permission manually from setting.
created auth_token and account_SID and added in fronted code.
Although not found any solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.